# XML Attributes to SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've seen posts that are similar to what I'm about to ask, but I can't find anything that actually solves my problem.  I've seen (and duplicated) getting XML tags into SQL, but not getting the attributes of the tags into SQL.

Background:  We use a program that runs "events" based on each event's schedule.  The schedules are in XML.  Ultimately, I'm trying to compare the last time a given event ran to the last time it should have run, based on its schedule.  Once I get the schedules out of XML and into a table (or tables), I'm confident I can take it from there.  But, I'm STRUGGLING with that first step.

Below is the XML I'm trying to get into a table (or tables).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
<Schedule LastModified="2016-06-27T21:02:10.6041531Z" TimeZone="(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada)" ConvertedToUTC="True" Type="Weekly">
    <Beginning StartDate="2016-05-26T22:26:00.0000000" />
    <Block BlockType="AllDay" Interval="10" IntervalType="Minute" SetType="Inclusive" Start="15:00:00" End="17:00:00" Duration="02:00:00" />
    <Interval Type="Weekly" RecurEveryX="1" Sunday="False" Monday="True" Tuesday="True" Wednesday="True" Thursday="True" Friday="True" Saturday="False" />
    <Ending Type="NoEndDate" />
</Schedule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, where you have your issues... Reading this XML is rather trivial (did not code all of the values, but you'll get the idea):

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(YourXML XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
(N'<Schedule LastModified="2016-06-27T21:02:10.6041531Z" TimeZone="(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada)" ConvertedToUTC="True" Type="Weekly">
    <Beginning StartDate="2016-05-26T22:26:00.0000000" />
    <Block BlockType="AllDay" Interval="10" IntervalType="Minute" SetType="Inclusive" Start="15:00:00" End="17:00:00" Duration="02:00:00" />
    <Interval Type="Weekly" RecurEveryX="1" Sunday="False" Monday="True" Tuesday="True" Wednesday="True" Thursday="True" Friday="True" Saturday="False" />
    <Ending Type="NoEndDate" />
</Schedule>');

SELECT m.YourXML.value(N'(/Schedule/@LastModified)[1]',N'datetime') AS Schedule_LastModified
      ,m.YourXML.value(N'(/Schedule/@TimeZone)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Schedule_TimeZone
      ,m.YourXML.value(N'(/Schedule/Beginning/@StartDate)[1]',N'datetime') AS Beginning_StartDate
      ,m.YourXML.value(N'(/Schedule/Block/@BlockType)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Block_BlockType
      ,m.YourXML.value(N'(/Schedule/Block/@Interval)[1]',N'int') AS Block_Interval
      ,m.YourXML.value(N'(/Schedule/Interval/@Type)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Interval_Type
FROM @mockup AS m;
```

If this is not your solution, please edit your question: Add your own attempt, the wrong output and the expected output. Your explanation did not make is all clear to me...